# Use variables in Bot::BasicBot constructor

Tags: perl, bots, irc

I'm using `Bot::BasicBot` to write a bot that logs chat. I have a config hashref that looks like this:

```
my $config = {  
    cryptokey => "a" x 32,  
    nickpass => "password",  
    nick => "loggerbot",  
    server => 'irc.foonetic.net',  
    port => 6697,  
    ssl => 1  
};
```

I have a separate config file that I use to read custom options into the hashref. I have tested it, and they read in correctly. However, when I add the items into the constructor

```
LogBot->new(

server => $config->{server},
port   => $config->{port},
ssl => $config->{ssl},
channels => ["#test"],

nick      => "$config->{nick}",
username => "loggerbot",
quit_message => "shutting down"
)->run();
```

The bot does not connect or even time out. It works if I omit the variables and just put the   values directly in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it nick or username property? or both?

Comment: It's both. I haven't added username to the config hash yet.

Comment: use `Data::Dumper` if not sure what parameters are passed to constructor. `use strict;` should be good idea as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using `Data::Dumper`. It turned out I forgot to chomp each line as I was reading in the config file, so the variables had newlines at the end.